# Chained 32bit msi is going to "Program Files" folder instead of "Program Files (x86)" folder on windows 7

Tags: windows-installer, advanced-installer

I have a Mixed Platform Installer developed using "Advanced Installer."
I have a second installer which is marked as 32-bit installer, and is installed with the main installer as a chained installation package.Default installation path is "C:\Program Files\Manufacturer"

Issue:
On Windows 10 64 bit,
Chained Msi package goes to "Program Files (x86)" folder. (Correct behaviour)
On Windows 7 64 bit,
Chained Msi package goes to "Program Files" folder.

I have tried setting InstallerPlatform to x86 in my chained component but it doesn't work. 
In log, on win 10, I could see is a step WIN64DUALFOLDERS: C:\Program Files (x86)\ will substitute 17 characters.  This is not found on windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried to install the chained setup alone on the Win 7 64 bit machine and see if the same thing happens? Try to create an MSI install log and attach it here.

Comment: Yes, I installed it alone and worked fine there. I will generate logs.